# Apply CSS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How can I apply elements like the following CSS in JavaScript:

```
.watch-non-stage-mode .player-width {
    width : 640px !important;
}
```

I tried doing this but it's not working:

```
document.getElementByClassName('.watch-non-stage-mode .player-width').style.width = '640px !important';
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Your pseudo code looks like it's attempting to just set an object to the same value as the CSS already specifies.  So, what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to use javascript by using the plugin grease monkey and change the size of YouTube videos to 640 x 360 i have already done this with css but i need JavaScript because  YouTube forces it to stretch to window size and it effects the video time.

here is my full css
https://userstyles.org/styles/103737/youtube-old-default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector('.watch-non-stage-mode .player-width').style.width = '640px'
```

or if `!important` is necessarily:

```
document.querySelector('.watch-non-stage-mode .player-width').style.cssText = 'width: 640px !important;'
```

In your case you also may use `getElementsByClassName`, but you incorrectly got a node, must be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('watch-non-stage-mode player-width')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The unit, 'px', and '!important' must be added to the property separately. Do:

```
document.querySelector('.watch-non-stage-mode .player-width').style.width = 640 + 'px' + '!important';
```

Also, use querySelector as noted  to select the elements by the actual dot classname. You cannot use '.classname' in the manner you show (which is incorrect anyway). Elements is plural. getElement**s**ByClassName